How to specify cleanup commands for `systemctl disable --now`?
I just learned the (hard way) that in a systemd service file, the ExecStopPost commands are not executed on
systemctl disable --now myservice.service

They are only executed on
systemctl stop myservice.service

(which might then be followed by systemctl disable myservice.service).
I have two questions on this:

What is the rationale behind that behaviour?
How can I specify cleanup commands that are also executed on systemctl disable --now?


Looking at the source code, systemctl disable --now is a simple combination of systemctl disable and systemctl stop.
If the service is already stopped when you run systemctl stop, the command does nothing. Likewise, if the service is enabled but stopped, systemctl disable --now does nothing different from systemctl disable without the --now option, i.e. it just disables the service auto-start at boot time.
Since systemd tracks processes by control groups, it knows whether or not any service process or any of its descendants are still running. If the service is not running, when you run systemctl disable --now, the possibilities are:

the service was stopped before, and any ExecStopPost actions were already executed at that time
the service was never started, and there is nothing to clean up
the entire system crashed while the service was running, so the ExecStopPost actions could not run. When the system restarted, the service either was already disabled (= did not attempt to start), or failed to start.

If you need automatic clean-up for your service after a system-wide crash, ExecStartPre might be a good place for it. If that is not suitable, you could always make the clean-up action a separate service unit, with appropriate dependencies between it and your main service unit.
(However, if your system crashes often enough that you need to automate post-crash clean-up like that, it seems to me it might be more useful to think about how one might avoid crashing in the first place... but I don't know your full context, so that's just me.)
